# Why does Maven deploy dependency in the middle of tests

Tags: maven, apache-axis

When one of the tests is run as part of the maven build, maven warns that it is deploying an axis2 library.  Where is it "deploying" it to and why does it do this?  The so called deployment takes between 3 seconds and 12 minutes.

The maven log message is as follows

> Running com.xxx.yyy.acceptance.RecalculationQueueItemCreateIntegrationTest
>   INFO  07-14 14:57:40 Deploying module: addressing-1.5.6 - file:/C:/repository/org/apache/axis2/axis2/1.5.6/axis2-1.5.6.jar  (ModuleDeployer.java:79)
>  
>   Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 290.522 sec

The delay (of between 3 seconds and 12 minutes) occurs after the INFO line is displayed.

Poor performance may have something to do with the generation of code as the only "addressing" in the code base occurs in source generated by wsdl2code.  However the test concerned does not seem to be directly concerned with XML processing and the code appears to have been fully generated by the time maven is "stuck".

This occurs with both maven 3.0.3 and maven 3.3.

Comment: Please post your pom.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for your interest Gabriel, I will do this but I will have to slim it down considerably first.

Comment: Are you running the tests multi-threaded? Perhaps the log is showing output from different threads. Also turning on debug logging with `-X` might help you see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks.  -X added nothing to the log.  It's all single threaded.